# I will like to open my pdf from GridHyperLinkColumn telerik radgrid table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, pdf, telerik

I will like help on opening pdf file stored in database from GridHyperLinkColumn, when i click on this column name "DisplayName" i want it to use target = _new to open my pdf file on the browser. Now i have being able to store the file in my MSSQL table using verbinary(MAX) and also open the link in a new browser but its not accessing the pdf file. my asp.net form source file is as given below:

```
    <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True">
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceGridArchive">
        <Columns>

            <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataTextField="DisplayName" FilterControlAltText="Filter DisplayName column" HeaderText="DisplayName" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="DisplayName" DataNavigateUrlFields="DisplayName" SortExpression="DisplayName" Target="_new" UniqueName="DisplayName">
            </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="doc_number" FilterControlAltText="Filter doc_number column" HeaderText="doc_number" SortExpression="doc_number" UniqueName="doc_number">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="doc_classification" FilterControlAltText="Filter doc_classification column" HeaderText="doc_classification" SortExpression="doc_classification" UniqueName="doc_classification">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="doc_date" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter doc_date column" HeaderText="doc_date" SortExpression="doc_date" UniqueName="doc_date">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceGridArchive" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pro_dbConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [DisplayName], [doc_number], [doc_classification], [doc_date] FROM [Document]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

the .cs source is also as shown below:
public partial class Archives : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadGrid1.ItemCommand += new GridCommandEventHandler(RadGrid1_ItemCommand);

```
    }

    protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //your code

        string sConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["pro_dbConnectionString"].ToString();
        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(sConn);
        objConn.Open();
        string sTSQL = "select * from Document";
        SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(sTSQL, objConn);
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(objCmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(dt);
        objConn.Close();
        objCmd.Dispose();
        //Bind the Data into the html anchor tag which will call the handler with ID  
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string tbl = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                tbl += @"<li>  
<a target='_blank' href='DocHandler.ashx?ID=" + dt.Rows[i]["SNo"].ToString();
                tbl += @"' title='";
                tbl += @"' >" + dt.Rows[i]["DisplayName"].ToString();
                tbl += @"</a>  
        </li>";
            }
            Response.Write(tbl);
        }

    }

}
```

I then created a handle with .ashx.cs extension to handle my file stream as given below:

public class DocHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        //context.Response.Write("Hello World");

        string id = context.Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
        string sConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["pro_dbConnectionString"].ToString();
        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(sConn);
        objConn.Open();
        string sTSQL = "select Name_File,Extension,ContentType,FileData,FileSize from Documente where SNo=@ID";
        SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(sTSQL, objConn);
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(objCmd);
        DataTable file = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(file);
        objConn.Close();
        objCmd.Dispose();
        if (file.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow row = file.Rows[0];
            string name = (string)row["Name_File"];
            string contentType = (string)row["ContentType"];
            Byte[] data = (Byte[])row["FileData"];
            int FileSize = Convert.ToInt32(row["FileSize"].ToString());
            // Send the file to the browser  
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-type", contentType);
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-   Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, FileSize);
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.End();
        }

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but i can't access this on my radgrid table but i can populate it on a simple webform, please i need help on this, so that when i click the hyperlink it loads my pdf file

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify controls in a grid column, use the ItemDataBound event. Also, see here for examples on how to access a concrete cell/column: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/rows/accessing-cells-and-rows - you will see that you need to change control properties and not use Response.Write().

Then, use the format string as it is supposed to be used, see here http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/columns/column-types#gridhyperlinkcolumn

If you need several links per grid row, you should use a Template column and create the list in a similar fashion to your current approach, but the code you have in ItemCommand should be in the ITemplate class (the InstantiateIn method), and you should, again, create controls/set an HTML string in a container rather than user Response.Write.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not work for me, i created an HyperLinkColumn for the DisplayName Column but it did not work. Please if you can provide a link to an example or help me with it.